# Clojure spec - naming entity keywords

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is it considered bad practice to use namespace-qualified keywords with nonexistent namespaces, for defining specs? I'd like to have entity maps defined in common *domain* namespace... so to avoid loosing data when merging specs, I've used convention `:entity/attribute` instead of `::entity-attribute` for attributes and standard `::entity` for entities. It aligns nicer to database tables and columns. Each entity in a separate namespace reminds me of Java classes, doesn't sound like a good idea.

```
(s/def :country/id   ::nilable-nat-int)
(s/def :country/name ::non-empty-string)

(s/def ::country
  (s/keys :req [:country/id
                :country/name]))

;; ----------------------------------------

(s/def :location/id      ::nilable-nat-int)
(s/def :location/name    ::non-empty-string)
(s/def :location/zipcode ::nilable-non-empty-string)

(s/def ::location
  (s/merge
   (s/keys :req [:location/id
                 :location/name
                 :location/zipcode])
   (s/or :country ::country
         :country-id
         (s/keys :req [:country/id]))))
```

Comment: On the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/TcRXF3a0bNI/pafdYbTnAwAJ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [@glts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279505/clojure-spec-naming-entity-keywords?noredirect=1#comment93457033_53279505) commented, here is the right answer: [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/TcRXF3a0bNI/EMn9EF6oBAAJ).

I've decided to make keywords more specific, added this to the domain namespace:

```
(doseq [ns ["entity-1" ,,, "entity-n"]]
  (->> (str "project.domain." ns)
       (symbol)
       (create-ns)
       (alias (symbol ns))))
```

And then `::entity-n/attribute` evaluates to `:project.domain.entity-n/attribute`.

Only one additional `:` is needed for the attributes from the question-example:

```
(s/def ::location/id ::nilable-nat-int)
```